# How do I change the device language before launching tests?

Tags: android, python, automated-tests, appium

I have the following screen scenario:

1. I have to check if my (physical) device is in English. If not, I have to switch to English.
2. I have to open my application and run my tests.

I wrote two functions: One to check the language and the other to switch the language. Then, in `setUp()` I check if it is English. Here's me code:

```
def setUp(self):
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.4'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = '0429058934'
    desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'C:/Users/andre.mendes/Desktop/workspace/powerpro/apps/powerpro.apk'))
    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.psafe.powerpro'
    desired_caps['appActivity'] = '.MainActivity'
    desired_caps['autoLaunch'] = False
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(15) 
    getLang = "adb -s 0429058934 shell getprop persist.sys.language"        
    ret = subprocess.check_output(getLang)
    lang = ret.strip()
    if lang != 'en':
        os.system("adb -s 0429058934 shell am start -a android.settings.LOCALE_SETTINGS")
        eng = self.driver.find_element_by_name('English (United Kingdom)')
        action = TouchAction(self.driver)
        action.press(eng).perform()
        action.move_to(x=0, y=50).perform()
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('English (United States)').click()
    self.driver.launch_app()
```

But how do I do it without launching my application? I tried:

```
desired_caps['autoLaunch'] = False
```

But I keep getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendAction' of null

Comment: i am not sure about the python but i worked on languages as well and i have one app to change the device language and it works pretty smooth. Plus i am not sure why would u like to know if you device is in english or not, because in my case i just change the language whatever i need without knowing my current language on my device

Comment: Is possible to create a session and run one app, close this session and start another one with my application under test? I just need it to make sure i'm testing in english, if it already in english i will save some time.

Comment: I see it very simple just add a validation @BeforeTest if(text="YourEnglishString") run test else change language and run test